# Redirect traffic from folder or its subfolders to another folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, configuration, forward

I've got an Apache Webserver running on the default `var/www/html` path.

This looks like the following:

```
var (Folder)
|   www (Folder)
|   |   html (Folder)
|   |   |   index.php (File)
|   |   |   some_other_files.php (File)
|   |   |   ab (Folder)
|   |   |   |   index.php
|   |   my_app (Folder)
|   |   |   ab.php (file)
|   |   |   login (Folder)
|   |   |   |   index.php
|   |   |   index.php (File)
```

Now I want to redirect all the traffic from `domain.com/my_app` and its subfolders to the actual `var/www/my_app` directory.

This should **not** just redirect the `var/www/html/index.php` file to `var/www/my_app/index.php`, but also all the traffic from the subfolders of `html` should be sent to the folders in `my_app` accordingly.

Examples:

```
domain.com/my_app/       => var/www/my_app/index.php
domain.com/              => var/www/html/index.php
domain.com/abc           => var/www/html/abc/index.php
domain.com/my_app/login/ => var/www/my_app/login/index.php
domain.com/my_app/ab.php => var/www/my_app/ab.php
```

*Note that this should FORWARD / REWRITE the requests to the folders, not just REDIRECT them!*

How can I achieve this either by implementing the propper `.htaccess` or editing the apache `conf` file?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The addition of the `/var/www/html` directory is creating a problem where there should be none.  If you define `DirectoryRoot /var/www` and forget about that `html` subdirectory, all your examples will work without having to do anything.  Requets to domain.com/ will go to `/var/www/`.  Requests to `domain.com/SOMETHING` will go to `/var/www/SOMETHING`.  You *could* use alias (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias), but this is creating work where none is required.  So remove `html` directory, move all files in there 1 level and you are done.

Comment: @Nic3500 that is indeed a clever idea, however, there‘s a problem: in /var/www, there are other folders that should not be accessible through the internet at all. Background: I use a PHP deployment tool called “Deployer”, which creates the following directories within /var/www/my_app/: “releases” and “current”. This “current” folder is a symlink to the most recent release. Now what I want to do is point the domain.com/my_app to this folder, so that only this exact folder (the most recent releases) is accessible... Thank you!

Comment: Instead of downvoting, could you please give me advice on how to improve this question?

Comment: ah ok, makes sense now not to use the top directory directly.  Your use of alias in your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

    Alias /my_app "/var/www/my_app/"
    Alias /my_app/ "/var/www/my_app/"
    <Directory "/var/www/my_app/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This way, all the HTTP traffic to `domain.com/my_app` gets sent to `/var/www/my_app/` and its subfolders accordingly!